# How to create new table with multiple columns from json table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table filled with json objects. There is only one column 'data'.

I would like to convert this table into one with multiple columns for all the keys in the json objects.

For example,

Right now my table is like this:

| data |
| --- |
| {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} |
| {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'} |

But I would like it like this:

| key1 | key2 |
| --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 |
| value3 | value4 |

I'm not trying to query it in this way, I would like to completely create a new table in the format that I've shown above.

I can try running:

```
INSERT INTO new_table 
SELECT data -> 'key1', data -> 'key2' 
FROM old_table
```

But since my json objects have hundreds of columns this may be inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do so? Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this way is more simple?

```
select t.*
from yourtable
cross join json_to_record(jsoncol) t(key1 text,key2 text,key3 text,...);
```

on the second thought , if you already have a table that matches the columns from your json , you can do this:

```
create table newTable (key1 text, key2 text , ...);

select t.*
from yourtable
cross join json_populate_record(null::newTable,jsoncol) t;
```

Comment: This command results in an out of memory error and when I limit to 1000 for example, it doesn't add anything to the new table. select count(*) returns 0 rows. I do have the new table with all the columns already created though.